# Sorry for another python imports questions

Tags: python, import

This is my projects structure:

```
 |-project
      |-tests
           |-test1.py   
      |-tools
           |-AuxillaryFunctions
```

I would like to be able to call functions from AuxillaryFunctions.py in test1.py.  I tried

`from tools import AuxillaryFunctions as AF`

`from .. import tools.AuxillaryFunctions as AF`

`from ..tools import AuxillaryFunctions as AF`

and seemingly everything else, but I keep getting ImportErrors.  Sorry for another imports question, just can't seem to get my head around this.

Comment: Do you have any `__init__.py` files?

Comment: I did, but that didn't fix the problem so I removed them

Comment: Keep the `__init__.py` files everywhere and call test1.py as module: `python -m tests.test1` (`from tools import AuxillaryFunctions as AF`)  ... or make a real package.

Answer (score 0):

Python only detects modules from same directory or pythonpath directory.

Solution 1:

Add "..\tools\AuxillaryFunctions" to PYTHONPATH Environmental varible

Solution 2:

Append module path to sys.path to detect modules at run time.

```
path = (os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "../../"),
                                             /'tools\\AuxillaryFunctions'))
sys.path.append(path)
from AuxillaryFunctions import AF
```